# Batch: "If string in output" within psexec (sending command chain)

Tags: batch-file, output, psexec, errorlevel

Dears,

I'm hoping you can help me with little project of mine.
For some time I was creating tool to handle my job quicker with less effort but same level of efficiency.

Here is part I'm having trouble with:

```
@echo off
title Hardware Check
color f
echo """""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
echo " _   _               _                         ____ _               _    "
echo "| | | | __ _ _ __ __| __      ____ _ _ __ ___ / ___| |__   ___  ___| | __"
echo "| |_| |/ _` | '__/ _` \ \ /\ / / _` | '__/ _ | |   | '_ \ / _ \/ __| |/ /"
echo "|  _  | (_| | | | (_| |\ V  V | (_| | | |  __| |___| | | |  __| (__|   < "
echo "|_| |_|\__,_|_|  \__,_| \_/\_/ \__,_|_|  \___|\____|_| |_|\___|\___|_|\_\"
echo """""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
echo "                                                                         "
echo """""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
echo.
echo "Which server do you want to check?"
echo.
set /p ans="Machine: "
echo.
psexec \\%ans% cmd /c (^ omreport system^ ^& echo.^ ^& omreport chassis^ ^& echo.^ ^& omreport storage pdisk controller=0^ ^& echo.^ ^& uptime^ ^& echo.^ ^& pause^ ^& echo.^)
echo. | findstr /I /B /C:"status" | findstr /I /C:"critical"
if %errorlevel%==0 (color c) else (color a)
echo.
pause
```

Idea is that after sending commands, batch should check if output data contains word "critical" and if so, color all text for red color, otherwise color for green color.

Example of text it should find and due to condition color red:

```
Status                          : Non-Critical
```

When I run this, it seems like batch doesn't really care if condition is fulfilled or not, it always color for green.
If you can see where is mistake and have idea how to fix it and make it work, I'd be grateful.

Comment: I guess it should read `psexec \\%ans% cmd /c ^( omreport ...` (note the `^(` but you had `(^`)... By the way, using quotation marks around the command after `cmd /C` avoids need of escaping anything...

Comment: In this small part of code " " instead of ( ) is true, yet it's just a small part of code, and for other parts where services and processes are started quatation marks are needed.
As I said part that does not work is one with coloring text :(

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for "status" and "critical" in the output of `echo.` not in the output of `psexec`. Since `echo.` never outputs anything more than an end of line, the batch file will never find the words "status" and "critical" and the color will always be green. To put it more simply, the code:

```
echo. | findstr /I /B /C:"status" | findstr /I /C:"critical"
if %errorlevel%==0 (color c) else (color a)
```

is strictly equivalent to `color a`.

Maybe you should capture the output of the remote commands in a file on the remote system, copy that file to the local system and the use `findstr` to look inside the copied file.

Comment: So far I spent hours thinking how to resolve it the way you shown it.
After adding anything after psexec passing command, psexec doesn't even start

Comment: @mgj1993: I confess that I did not read exactly what commands you passed to `cmd`, because the question was why the color is always green. The answer to that question is correct -- you are using a very complicated way to say `color a`. For the specific use case, you should capture the output of the remote commands in a file on the remote system, copy that file to the local system and the use `findstr` to look inside the copied file.

Comment: I wish I could. Another limitation is I can not put on any machine any files :(

Comment: The put it on the local machine (the one where you run `psexec` -- `cmd /c "some command >\\LocalMachine\Temp\Output.txt"`.